# Passing a table as argument to function in Lua

Tags: function, lua, arguments, lua-table

I want to loop through different indexed tables by only passing the initial table as an argument.
I currently have this table:

```
local table = {
stuff_1 = {
    categories = {},
    [1] = { 
        name = 'wui',
        time = 300
    }
},
stuff_2 = {
    categories = {'stuff_10', 'stuff_11', 'stuff_12'},
    stuff_10 = {
        categories = {},
        [1] = {
            name = 'peo',
            time = 150
        },
        [2] = { 
            name = 'uik',
            time = 15
        },
        [3] = { 
            name = 'kpk',
            time = 1230
        },  
        [4] = {     
            name = 'aer',
            time = 5000
        }
    },
    stuff_11 = {
        categories = {},
        [1] = { 
            name = 'juio',
            time = 600
        }
    },
    stuff_12 = {
        categories = {},
        [1] = {
            name = 'erq',
            time = 980
        },
        [2] = {
            name = 'faf',
            time = 8170
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a recursive function to check if the name in any of those tables was equal to some certain thing and return a string.
The recursivity lies in the idea of updating this table with whatever ammount I'd like (or until a certain limit).
I don't understand exactly what's wrong since when I try:

```
for k, v in pairs(table) do
    print(k, v, #v.categories)
end
```

It correctly prints:

```
stuff_2 table: 0x10abb0 3
stuff_1 table: 0x10aab8 0
```

But when passing the table as a parameter to the the function below, it gives this error:

```
[string "stdin"]:84: attempt to get length of field 'categories' (a nil value)
```

Function:

```
function checkMessage(table)
    local i = 1
    local message = ""

    for k, v in pairs(table) do 
        if(#v.categories == 0) then  
            while(v[i]) do 
                if(v[i].name == 'opd') then 
                    if(v[i].time ~= 0) then 
                        message = "return_1"
                    else 
                        message = "return_2"
                    end 
                end 
                i = i + 1 
            end
        else
            checkMessage(table[k])
        end 
    end 
    return message 
end
```

EDIT: The problem lies in not ignoring that when using pairs onto the table, this doesn't just have tables with a category subtable but it also has a table named category, if this is ignored then the problem is fixed.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to search tables for names, then you'd better off restructuring your tables to have names as keys, not as values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're recursing into subtables that don't have a `categories` field. Trying to access `categories` on them yields `nil`, which you then try to use the length operator on. Hence your error:

```
  attempt to get length of field 'categories' (a nil value)
```

If you can't hand trace your app, put in more print statements or get a line level debugger.

Comment: The question remains though, why don't they have a categories field whilst the subtables of the table passed as argument do? I can also print #v.categories inside the function but can't use it as a conditional.. hmm?

Comment: Not all of the subtables *do* have that field, and it's failing on one that *doesn't* (e.g. the categories table itself). This was pretty obvious to me looking at your code, but even if you didn't see that by reading, it's the kind of thing a few more print statements and/or a debugger would revealed for you.